# I am doing a simple Moderation regression: there is multicolinearity in my model when I add the interaction term. I want to check if this is ok

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, multicollinearity, psychology

The first step of my regressionmodel with both predictor variables and the outcome variable meet all assumptions. However when I add the second term there is multicolinearity. This seems obvious since the interaction term is related to both the predictor variables, however I am unconfident with stats and I want to make sure that it is ok for me to ignore this.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Many reserachers have thought the opposite, but multicolinearity is not a problem in moderation analysis. See this [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27531361/) for instance. So, yes you can ignore it at the moment.